# Как сохранить данные парсинга в csv файл, чтобы его можно было читать и записывать?

Tags: python, requests, csv, dict

столкнулся с проблемой у меня есть код который должен сохранять данные полученные с парсера в CSV файл уметь его читать и записывать, но у меня не получется положить результаты парсинга в data:
Код парсера parser.py:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import data_client


class Parser:
    links_to_parse = [
        'https://www.kufar.by/l/mebel',
        'https://www.kufar.by/l/mebel?cursor=eyJ0IjoiYWJzIiwiZiI6dHJ1ZSwicCI6MiwicGl0IjoiMjg0NjI5MDcifQ%3D%3D',
        'https://www.kufar.by/l/mebel?cursor=eyJ0IjoiYWJzIiwiZiI6dHJ1ZSwicCI6MywicGl0IjoiMjg0NjI5MDcifQ%3D%3D',
        'https://www.kufar.by/l/mebel?cursor=eyJ0IjoiYWJzIiwiZiI6dHJ1ZSwicCI6NiwicGl0IjoiMjg0NjI5MDcifQ%3D%3D'
    ]
    data_client_imp = data_client.CsvClient()

    @staticmethod
    def get_mebel_by_link(link):
        response = requests.get(link)
        mebel_data = response.text

        mebel_items = []
        to_parse = BeautifulSoup(mebel_data, 'html.parser')
        for elem in to_parse.find_all('a', class_='styles_wrapper__5FoK7'):
            try:
                price, decription = elem.text.split('р.')
                mebel_items.append((
                    elem['href'],
                    int(price.replace(' ', '')),
                    decription
                ))
            except:
                print(f'Цена не была указана. {elem.text}')

        return mebel_items

    def save_to_postgres(self, mebel_items):
        connection = self.data_client_imp.get_connection()
        self.data_client_imp.create_mebel_table(connection)
        for item in mebel_items:
            self. data_client_imp.insert(connection, item[0], item[1], item[2])

    def run(self):
        mebel_items = []
        for link in Parser.links_to_parse:
            mebel_items.extend(self.get_mebel_by_link(link))
        self.save_to_postgres(mebel_items)


Parser().run()
```

КОД Data_Client

```
import csv
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
# pip install psycopg2
import psycopg2
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import pandas as pd
import os
from parser import Parser


class DataClient(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_connection(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def create_mebel_table(self, conn):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_items(self, conn, price_from=0, price_to=100000):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def insert(self, conn, link, price, description):
        pass

    def run_test(self):
        data = []
        conn = self.get_connection()
        self.create_mebel_table(conn)
        parsed_data = Parser.get_mebel_by_link()
        for item in parsed_data:
            data.append({
                'link': item[0],
                'price': item[1],
                'description': item[2]
            })

        for item in data:
            self.insert(conn, item['link'], item['price'], item['description'])

        items = self.get_items(conn, price_from=10, price_to=30)
        for item in items:
            print(item)



class PostgresClient(DataClient):
    USER = "postgres"
    PASSWORD = "postgres"
    HOST = "localhost"
    PORT = "5432"

    def get_connection(self):
        try:
            connection = psycopg2.connect(
                user=self.USER,
                password=self.PASSWORD,
                host=self.HOST,
                port=self.PORT
            )
            return connection
        except Error:
            print(Error)

    def create_mebel_table(self, conn):
        cursor_object = conn.cursor()
        cursor_object.execute(
            """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mebel
                (
                    id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
                    link text, 
                    price integer, 
                    description text
                )
            """
        )
        conn.commit()

    def get_items(self, conn, price_from=0, price_to=100000):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM mebel WHERE price >= {price_from} and price <= {price_to}')
        return cursor.fetchall()

    def insert(self, conn, link, price, description):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO mebel (link, price, description) VALUES ('{link}', '{price}', '{description}')")
        conn.commit()


class Sqlite3Client(DataClient):
    DB_NAME = "kufar.db"

    def get_connection(self):
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(self.DB_NAME)
            return conn
        except Error:
            print(Error)

    def create_mebel_table(self, conn):
        cursor_object = conn.cursor()
        cursor_object.execute(
            """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mebel
                (
                    id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, 
                    link text, 
                    price integer, 
                    description text
                )
            """
        )
        conn.commit()

    def get_items(self, conn, price_from=0, price_to=100000):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM mebel WHERE price >= {price_from} and price <= {price_to}')
        return cursor.fetchall()

    def insert(self, conn, link, price, description):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO mebel (link, price, description) VALUES ('{link}', '{price}', '{description}')")
        conn.commit()

class CsvClient(DataClient):
    FILENAME = 'mebel.csv'

    def get_connection(self):
        return None

    def create_mebel_table(self, conn):
        pass

    class CsvClient(DataClient):
        FILENAME = 'mebel.csv'

    def get_connection(self):
        return None

    def create_mebel_table(self, conn):
        pass

    def get_items(self, conn, price_from=0, price_to=100000):
        items = []
        with open(self.FILENAME, 'r', newline='') as file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file)
            for row in reader:
                price = int(row['price'])
                if price >= price_from and price <= price_to:
                    items.append(row)
        return items

    def insert(self, conn, link, price, description):
        with open(self.FILENAME, 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([link, price, description])




data_client = CsvClient()
data_client.run_test()
```

Пробовал импортировать parser.py и передать в дата функцию get_mebel_by_link(), но выдаёт ошибку и данные парсинга не ложаться в data

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Первый раз пользуюсь данным сервисом, Я учусь, так что извините, если что то не так

Comment: Вопрос уже не актуальный